# Cors Problem in Next.JS interface with ASP.Net API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, next.js, next.js13

I have a problem when access the ASP.net API controller method with authorization method.
When trying to post request from nextjs side, it gives error like this:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:5001/api/AdayHesabim/GetAllAdayOnYazi/2' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

Thanks from now anyone helping to me.

I already have access to backend so i set it up already my Startup.cs like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddControllers();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddTransient<IValidator<Aday>, AdayProfilValidator>();
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:3000");
                        builder.WithHeaders("content-type");
                        builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                        builder.AllowCredentials();
                    });
            });

            services.AddScoped<DbContext, SqlDbContext>();
            services.AddScoped<ITransactionManager, TransactionScopeManager>();

            // JWT authentication Aayarlaması

            string securityKey = "**********";
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(securityKey);
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
               ...
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
               ...
            });

            #region Aday 

            services.AddScoped<IAdayHesabimService, AdayHesabimManager>();
            ...
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            }); 
        }
```

I tried also with like this policy too:

```
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                        builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                        builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                    });
```

Always when i tryng to make POST reequest to https://localhost:5001/api/AdayHesabim/GetAllAdayOnYazi/2 it gives same error. How can i solve this?
Also my code in nextjs side like this:

```
export const getAdayOnyazilar = async (id,token) => {
  
  console.log(`Bearer ${token}, ${id}`);
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/AdayHesabim/GetAllAdayOnYazi/${id}`,{
      headers:{
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
    return response.data; // return only the data property of the response
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
      return error.response.data;
    } else {
      console.log("Bir hata oluştu. Lütfen tekrar deneyin. " + error);
      return "Bir hata oluştu. Lütfen tekrar deneyin. " + error;
    }
  }
};
```

When i try to make request from the Postman it can turning the results without any problem.